# The user is not associated with a trusted SQL Server connection error

Tags: java, android, sql-server

I am facing this error right now and tried various solution such as selecting sql server and windows authentication mode and giving the highest permission to the user. However, the same error still occur so is there any other suggestions?

ERROR: java.sql.SQLException: Login failed for user 'user'. The user is not associated with a trusted SQL Server connection.

EDIT:
I have tried the solution [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/adapters-and-accelerators/adapter-sql/connect-to-sql-server-using-windows-authentication-with-the-sql-adapter) as well but to no avail. I am also using jdbc and jtds as the driver.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy!

Follow steps :

1.Open SQL Server Management Studio connection and right-click on Server Node and select Properties.

2.Go to security tab

3.Under Server Authentication -> Select SQL Server and Windows Authentication Mode and press Ok.

You are ready to Go....!

Comment: Hi, the error remains even though i have select mixed authentication.

Comment: I forgot to add one point. Restart your Sql service and then retry!

Comment: Done that, still the same.